# Date format in mysql, how to make query with convertion?

Tags: php, mysql

I have old database which use date data in this format: 
[image: date format in db]

How should look a query which use a date year as a condition. I have wrote this one but I know that is incorrect. Exist some way to convert this date to this numbers in db?

```
$year = 2010 + $j;
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT *
FROM `swt_news`
WHERE (`date` >= '".$year."-00-00' AND `date` <= '".$year."-12-31') 
ORDER BY date DESC");
```

Unfortunatelly I can't change this how date looks in db :/

Comment: What you're looking at is a unix timestamp. You can use the function `FROM_UNIXTIME` to turn it into a datetime.

Comment: Since you are defining `$year` variable. Why not use `strtotime()`? and use that in your query.

Comment: Beacze - of course you can!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert the unix time to a date. Then extract the year in the `where` clause

```
SELECT *, 
       FROM_UNIXTIME(date) AS dt
FROM swt_news
WHERE year(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = $year
ORDER BY date DESC
```